How to temporarily disable the MySql server port
I have to software installed in my pc , one is navicat MySQL and other one is xampp . Now i want to start the mysql in xampp but the other software not letting me to start the server saying 3306 port is already in use. i dont want to uninstall the the application . Is there any way to temporarily free the port .
I tried changing the port number in config file but no use

clear port number through windows command

one is navicat MySQL and other one is xampp There are 2 options. 1st option - each software have installed its own MySQL instance, in this case you must to reconfigure one of the applications and its MySQL instance for some another port usage. 2nd option - both software uses the same MySQL instance, in this case you must start MySQL service manually/automatically and reconfigure your applications not to start MySQL service because it is already running.
